# Hook keyboard shortcuts from Windows lock screen

Tags: c, windows, winapi, keyboard, hook

I have an arduino in keyboard emulation mode that sends keyboard keystrokes to the computer it's connected to, the latter appending a log line in a local webpage upon receiving each keystroke. The log program is coded in C using Win32 API.

Now, since it's supposed to function at work (the idea is to get a log file online of when pushbuttons on my desk have been activated), I will be locking my computer...

How can I keep processing CTRL+ALT+key strokes from the windows lock screen?

Thanks,
Mister Mystère

Comment: Is there a simpler way than to write a service? If not, how to proceed in the simplest way possible?

Comment: this might help http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_system/keyboard/article.php/c4829/Managing-LowLevel-Keyboard-Hooks-with-the-Windows-API.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This may have been implicit, but I already have my hooks in place - they just don't function on the lock screen. I've updated my post to indicate I'm coding in C also.

Comment: I don´t think that this is possible.

Comment: Using services it should (others have succeeded), but I can't get it to work (see answer below)...

Comment: My apologies, it WAS possible before Vista. Now services are completely isolated and it is not possible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up downloading a third party lock screen and my program works in its background as it is a standard program. For those of you in the same situation, as far as I know after all that research I'm afraid you'll have to do that instead: it seems like it is not possible starting from Vista.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

When you run the compiled executable, the keys `A` and `B` are detected globally even when the screen is locked.